Android osmdroid - Do not show direction arrow when user is moving?
I am implementing an app for a neuroscience experiment where subjects have to navigate in an urban environment. By default osmdroid shows a direction arrow on the users location when they are moving. I want to always show the default (or any other) icon on the users' location.
I tried setting the direction icon to org.osmdroid.library.R.drawable.person, which makes it always use the default icon but it is then rotated according to the current direction. How do I disable the rotation?
